# How can I find column in matrix that matches 2 rows in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-indexing

I have a matrix, that I want to find a column that has item in row1 == x, and item in row2 == y;  What is the fastest way to do this?
Thanks,
CP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for a given matrix `M` and row indices `row1` and `row2`:

```
columnIndices = find((M(row1,:) == x) & (M(row2,:) == y));
```

Answer (score 6):

Consider:

```
colIdx = all( bsxfun(@eq, M([row1 row2],:), [x;y]) );
```

This is flexible in case you want to match more than two rows